# Magento 2: Broken Order print pdf layout in Mozilla

Tags: magento2, sales-order, forms, sales, print

[image]When taken a print order from My account ->My orders-> View Order-> Print Order, getting a broken layout on Fire fox web browser, But there is no issue on Chrome browser. How to fix this issue in Fire fox.

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you download the pdf, is it still broken? If it is, you should inspect what values does the browser pass to backend and how they affect pdf generation. In general PDF is 100% generated in the backend and should not depend on which browser you use

Comment: Alternatively you could fix it by modifying sales_order_pring.xml in Magento_Sales (in your custom template). What worked for me was moving `.order-details-items.ordered` and `.block.block-order-details-view` from wrapper divs directly under the `<body>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

It is happening because **firefox is printing headers and footers along with the page content**.To resolve this ,it seems you are using ubuntu so try following.

If you want to remove the header or footer permanently (there's no user interface like in Page Setup on Windows to easily change either) in Firefox on Linux, you can clear the various preferences Values to get rid of both them.

Type `about:config` in the URL bar and hit Enter. If you see the warning, you can confirm that you want to access that page.
`Filter = header`   Right-click each of those prefs and select Modify, then backspace or use Delete to wipe the characters - then click OK.
Repeat the same for footer.

If your clients are using windows ask them to follow this tutorial - https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/the-geek-blog/prevent-firefox-or-internet-explorer-from-printing-the-url-on-every-page/

Comment: Thanks for the reply... i'm using ubuntu  and followed the above steps. The header and footer removed. But still the contents are loading in the 2nd page. Updated the current situation screenshot to the main question.

Comment: can you post the screenshot of view order page ?

Comment: Screenshot updated

Comment: Removed Header and Footer. The Order Information is still broken. Shipping and Billing information is displayed one below other. Also I cant find option to remove header and footer in chrome.